# How to set property value in hidden input's tag. Angular 2

Tags: angular, input

I have component with template which have input's tag.
I need to set somehow the value to my classes public property.

How to do this?

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'delivery-additional-html',
   template: `<input type="hidden" #var [value]="'123'"/>`
})
class CustomDeliveryAdditionalHTML implements AfterViewInit {

   @Input('var') delivery_extra: any;
   
   ngAfterViewInit()
   {
       console.log(this.delivery_extra); //Show undefined
   }
}
```

I want to have in this.delivery_extra the "123" value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
@Input('var') delivery_extra: any = 123;
```

and then perhaps

```
template: `<input type="hidden" #var [value]="delivery_extry"/>`
```

**update**

```
@ViewChild('var') myInput:ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.myInput.nativeElement.value);
}
```

Comment: No, No. I need to SET delivery_extra from template attribute value.

Comment: Why that? Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Because I get template from remote server. I need to set value inside to operate it inside class.

Comment: What do you mean with "get template from remote server". When do you get that from the remote server? When you build your Angular application?

Comment: It still sounds very weird to me, but I updated my answer.

Comment: I have PHP Server that give me a template for Angular application. And I use templateUrl to request this template. ViewChild must to changed in your example to @ViewChild('delivery_extra') delivery_extra: ElementRef; Thank you very much that works.